# Cant use ActionBarDrawerToggle due to target sdk version

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

So long story short ive needed to mess with the dependencies section of the gradle so i had to replace the support for v4 due to a new taget sdk version. Because i cant use v4 support actionbardrawertoggle dosent appear to be showing up anymore which is needed for me to use the navigation drawer properly what can i do is there a way i can still use v4? or is there a simple alternative to actionbardrawertoggle?

Comment: Why can't you use the v4 support library? What is you new taget sdk?

Comment: paste the build.gradle files of your project

Comment: i changed the target sdk from 19 to 23

Comment: i used to have this compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0' in dependencies in gradle however it was giving me an error when i changed the target sdk version so ive been looking for an alternative but not much luck and now as a result i cant seem to import actionbardrawertoggle as well as drawer layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out all i needed to do was change com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0 to com.android.support:support-v7:23.0.0' (i switched it to v7 due to v4 being deprecated). I did actually try this earlier however i forgot to ad the '.0.0' at the end which caused the issue. Hope this helps anyone who has the issue.